# When the logarithm and integral can be commuted?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> When the Logarithm and integral  can be commuted?
>   [image: See this]

Comment: This isn't even a question.

Comment: They will almost never commute, since $\ln$ is concave.

Comment: Is your integral is $\int e^{r/x} dx$? In general, it is not true that $\ln\left( \int f(x) \ dx\right) = \int \ln(f(x)) \ dx$.

Comment: Note that if the given derivation were correct, then $\frac{d}{du} u^r=e^{r/u}$, which is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, and the conclusion reached on the attached photo, namely that

> $$
> \int^x e^{\frac{\mu}{t}}dt=x^\mu
> $$

is false.  In fact, the value of the indefinite integral is

$$
xe^{\frac{\mu}{x}}-\mu Ei\left(\frac{\mu}{x}\right)
$$

where $Ei$ is the elliptic integral function (e.g., see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E%7Bmu%2Ft%7D+dt)).